# On experience cloud for mobile (android) button 'Save' is not visible on standard record creation window (screen attached)

Tags: mobile, experience-cloud, ui

In the android mobile version of experience site on object list page I have a standard 'New' button (without override), which opens the standard record creation modal. When user logs in to the system and clicks button 'New' for the first time, button 'Save' in the record creation window is missing. Every next time button 'New' is clicked the issues is not reproduced. For iPhone the issues is not reproduced. For desktop the issue is not reproduced.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

[image: clicking 'New' button first time after login: no 'Save' button]

[image: clicking 'New' button second time: 'Save' button present]